# JQuery script not loading correctly

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I got one controller called `Profile` with several function such as `get_user_timeline` and `do_upload`. The `get_user_timeline` loaded into `profile_view` with ajax call from JQuery. It's functionality is to pull twitter timeline every 60 second.

It was running well after i put a form into the view to call the do_upload function. `do_upload` functionality is to upload file such as picture or mp3 to server. I put form validation into that function so when user didn't fill the entire from he/she will redirect back to `profile_view`with some warning. I did it by calling `$this->index()` in the `do_upload` function.

When i tested my code, I submitted the form with several input left blank. The `profile_view` loaded with nice form validation error warning, but it seems my Jquery won't work anymore because it doesn't display the twitter timeline. I checked the url.. it's say `http://localhost/myproject/profile/do_upload` instead `http://localhost/myproject/profile` . Is it CI default behavior? how to deal with it? it seems my Jquery only works with the `http://localhost/myproject/profile` could you give any advices guys? thanks

here's my code.
The profile controller

```
<?php

class Profile extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('tweet');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('user_model');

    }

    function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') == TRUE)
        {

            $data['biography'] = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata('user_id'));


            $data['user'] = $this->tweet->call('get', 'users/show', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')));

            $data['main_content'] = 'private_profile_view';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }
        else
        {

            redirect('welcome');
        }
    }


    /** timeline features **/
    function get_home_timeline()
    {
        $timeline = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/home_timeline');
        echo json_encode($timeline);

    }


//the do_upload function
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './media/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3';
        $config['max_size'] = '30720';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Song title', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('album', 'Album', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('artist', 'Artist', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('song_license_agreement', 'License', 'required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index(); //this return the warning but make my Jquery fail
        }
    }
```

THE .JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){


                update_timeline('profile/get_home_timeline', '#home_timeline ul', 'home'); //this is call to the timeline, this won't work if i submit the upload form

});

function update_timeline()
{
   //my ajax call goes here
}
```

THE VIEW

```
<div id="timeline" class="">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home_timeline" id="home_timeline_menu">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#user_timeline" id="user_timeline_menu">MyStatus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#mentions_timeline" id="mentions_timeline_menu">@me</a></li>
            </ul>
            <section id="home_timeline">
                <ul>
                   <!-- this is where the timeline goes -->
                </ul>
            </section>
<div>
<!-- and this is the form -->
<article id="music_upload_form">

                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                <?php echo form_open_multipart('profile/do_upload');?>
                <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->id_str;?>" />
                <label for="title">Song Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="30" value="<?php echo set_value('title'); ?>"/><br />
                <label for="album"> Album Title </label>
                <input type="text" name="album" id="album" size="30" value="<?php echo set_value('album'); ?>"/><br />
                <label for="artist">Artist</label>
                <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist" size="20" value="<?php echo set_value('artist'); ?>"/><br />
                <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /><br />
                <input type="radio" name="owner" id="license" value="<?php echo set_value('owner'); ?>"/>I AM the artist/owner of this song and I have the right for distribution<br />
                <input type="radio" name="licensed_user" id="license" value="<?php echo set_value('licensed_user');?>"/>I AM NOT the artist/owner of this song BUT I have the right for distribution</br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="song_license_agreement" value="<?php echo set_value('song_license_agreement');?>"/>By selecting this option, I swear that all information entered is right<br />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload Your Song" />
                </form>
            </article>
```

Comment: ups, sorry.. my English is bad. i will post my code. wait a minute :-)

Comment: @Madmartigan: I did some edits, hopefully it will be easier to understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I *think* I get what's going on here.

Instead of calling `$this->index()`, which just runs the `index()` method in the current one, redirect the user instead.

```
function do_upload()
{
    if ($error)
    {
        redirect('profile');
    }
}
```

Calling `$this->index()` doesn't actually change the URL or current method, it just runs whatever code you have there.

To get the errors to display on the next page, you can assign them to a session item:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
```

Then in your view:

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('errors');
```

I used flashdata because it will automatically be cleared on the next request. You might want to look into writing or adopting some kind of feedback/message library.

Comment: I've tried your solution. It works and it shows the timeline. but  now, the form error won't display... T_T